# add to cart url is not working

Tags: url, addtocart

I used this as my code:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)
```

It gives output of 'url' like this:

```
http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMC43OC9wb29qYS90ZXN0bWFnZW50by9pbmRleC5waHAvYWRtaW4vc3lzdGVtX2NvbmZpZy9lZGl0L3NlY3Rpb24vd2VvX3Byb2R1Y3RsaXN0L2tleS82Y2IzOWRmYTlmMTZkMzEzMzIzN2MzMjJmZjhhYjQ4ZC8,/product/1/form_key/iX6KKIWPRWIdICmy/
```

Above 'url' is not correct. How can I get correct 'url' for add to cart product?

Thanks.

Comment: you are using right code to get url, on which page you are trying to get url?

Comment: i am creating a custom module. i am using this code in "Block". @Piyush

Comment: you are getting correct url , whats incorrect in it?

Comment: @Piyush when i am hitting this url, product not add to cart and redirect to cart page.

Comment: there may be some other issue than url, check your log files

Comment: ok let me check @Piyush